# Parse - Notification not being received

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to send a `Parse` `Push Notification` from one Android application to all others.

The following is the set-up code in my `Application` object:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Game.class);
Parse.initialize(this, "code", "code");
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParseHelper.SUBSCRIPTION_CHANNEL_GAME);
```

The following is the `Push Notification` code:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String message = "Hello";
push.setChannel(ParseHelper.SUBSCRIPTION_CHANNEL_GAME);
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateGameActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(CreateGameActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    break;
}
```

Even though the `Success` `Toast` is called, I still don't see the Notification appearing on any of the two Android devices I have installed the app on.

I have tested the `Push Notifications` via `www.parse.com`'s Dashboard and that *does* work. Why won't it work in my app though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send notifications from a device, you have to do one extra step. Go into the settings of your app on parse and enable **Client Push**. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Aashir for president!